# Using BasicHTTPBinding WCF service from Silverlight breaks when turning on security

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, basichttpbinding

I'm trying to consume a BasicHTTPBinding WCF service (which is self-hosted in a .Net 4.0 console application) from Silverlight (v5). It all works fine when there's no transport encryption, but I'd like to wrap the traffic in a layer of SSL. There's no need for any kind of authentication.

With transport security turned on, I get the internal exception

> {System.Security.SecurityException --->
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.    at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.b*_9(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(Object
>   sendState)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttp
>   WebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)}

Here's the code:

**Server - not working (with security)**

```
baseAddress = new Uri("https://mysite.com:8080/myService"); 
BasicHttpBinding externalBinding = new BasicHttpBinding{                                                              MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000,
MaxBufferPoolSize = 1000000,
SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
Security = {Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport}                                          
                                                   };

           externalBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType=HttpClientCredentialType.None;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPolicyRetriever), wsbinding, "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ImyServiceService), externalBinding, "myService");
```

**Server working (no security)**

```
baseAddress = new Uri("http://mysite.com:8080/myService"); 

BasicHttpBinding externalBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000,
MaxBufferPoolSize = 1000000,
SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                                   }    ;

host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPolicyRetriever), wsbinding, "").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ImyServiceService), externalBinding, "myServiceService");
```

**SL client not working (with security)**

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://mysite.com:8080/myService");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);                                  
client = new myServiceServiceReference.myServiceServiceClient(binding, address);
```

**SL client working (no security)**

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://mysite.com:8080/myService");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();                           
client = new myServiceServiceReference.myServiceServiceClient(binding, address);
```

**clientaccesspolicy.xml**

```
<xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<access-policy>
 <cross-domain-access>
   <policy>
    <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
    <domain uri=""*""/></allow-from>
    <grant-to><resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
    </grant-to></policy>
 </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

I've tried changing `http-request-headers` to `https-request-headers` to no avail.

Can anyone see what's wrong; what do I need to do to enable simple SSL security on this BasicHTTPBinding?

Comment: Does your server provide a perfectly valid (!) certificate for security? Try to open your service url in a browser with https and check the browsers warnings.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that: yes, there is a proper, valid certificate bound to *:8080.

Comment: Can you build a small console application and test the connection there? Silverlight is very (!) picky about what it considers a valid certificate.

Comment: OK interesting - a console application (using security) connects fine. Any advice on what I can do to track down the issue that Silverlight has with this certificate?

Comment: You can use the following code to check for ssl errors in your console application. Sadly, this feature is missing from Silverlight, so it's guesswork there. `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { Console.WriteLine(sslPolicyErrors); return true; });`

Comment: `sslPolicyErrors` shows "none" :(

Comment: Solved the problem - see below. @nvoigt, thanks for your help: the console application idea helped narrow my attention away from the WCF code itself and towards what Silverlight was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cracked it. The problem, bizarrely enough, is with the `<domain uri=""*""/>` line in the `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file - for SSL it has to explicitly include HTTPS. So the working file looks like:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <access-policy>  
<cross-domain-access>
 <policy>
    <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
      <domain uri="http://*"/>
      <domain uri="https://*"/>
     </allow-from>
    <grant-to>
       <resource path=""/"" include-subpaths=""true""/>
    </grant-to>
   </policy> 
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Strange, but apparently true.